# Generic array sorting

Tags: java

The error I am getting is class expected?
I want to be able to pass in an array of anything. 
I do not understand why it does not work.

```
  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T Max(T value[])
      {
           T max = value[0];

           for(int x = 0; x < value[].length; x++) //here I get the error
           {
               if(value[x].compareTo(max) > 0)
                   max = value[x];
           }


          return max;
      }
```

Comment: `value.length` not `value[].length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `value[].length`? Correct would be `value.length`.